# HashSet on collections of objects

Tags: c#, .net, hashset, gethashcode

I have an object of type `T` which implements `IEquatable<T>` (methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are implemented). I use these objects in a `HashSet<T>`. But for my development I need to upgrade the elements of this hash set to collections of `T` objects (lists or arrays will both work, for instance I will use `HashSet<List<T>>`). These collections (`List<T>` for instance) have default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, but how can I override them such that two collections are said to be equal if and only if they are sequentially equal? And how to get an appropriate `GetHashCode`? Is this functionality already present in .Net in some way? I could define a new type `TT` which wraps a `List<T>` for instance, and implements `IEquatable<TT>` and use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` in the `Equals` method. But what about `GetHashCode`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` has a [constructor which takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__). You can use this to customise how the `HashSet<T>` compares its elements.

Something like:

```
public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        if (x is null && y is null)
            return true;
        if (x is null || y is null)
            return false;
    
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj is null)
            return 0;
    
        var hashCode = new HashCode();
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            hashCode.Add(item);
        }
        return hashCode.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then:

```cs
var hashSet = new HashSet<List<YourType>>(new ListEqualityComparer<YourType>());
```